# How can I clear the contents of a "comboBox" after I have submitted a form

Tags: c#, foreach, combobox

I am trying to clear the contents of a Windows form in C# after I have submitted the data.

I have managed to do this for text boxes using the following code:

```
foreach (Control c in Controls)
{
    if (c is TextBox)
    {
        c.Text = "";
```

However, I am struggling to complete the same task for the "comboBoxes" within the form. I have tried to use a variation of the code as follows but this does not seem to work.

```
if (c is ComboBox)
{
    c.Text = "";
```

So full code looks as follows:

```
 foreach (Control c in Controls)
 {
     if (c is TextBox)
     {
         c.Text = "";
     }
     if (c is ComboBox)
     {
         c.Text = "";
     }
```

Can anyone suggest a resolution, what am I missing?

Kind Regards

Ian

Comment: use `comboBox.Items.Clear();`

Comment: Are you talking about WinForms combobox or? And how do you fill the combo at the beginning of your code? This is required to tell you the effective way to clear the combo items

Comment: Yes a WinForms combobox and the drop down style is "DropDownList".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code goes like this:

```
//your submission of the form code here...

foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
    if (c is TextBox)
    {                    
        ((TextBox)c).Clear();
        //c.Text = String.Empty;
    }
    if (c is ComboBox)
    {
        ((ComboBox)c).Items.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks Rakitic, you suggestion works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
if (c is ComboBox)
{
    c.Items.Clear();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For example say you want to clear all of the TextBoxes, you could do something like this

```
YourForm.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList().ForEach(textBox => textBox.Clear());
```

For a ComboBox you could do the same thing

```
YourForm.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>().ToList().ForEach(comboBox => comboBox.Items.Clear());
```